# Get list of recently used Jenkins slaves

Tags: jenkins

Is there a tool or API i can use to give me a list of Jenkins slaves/nodes that have been used
to run builds recently (ex: within 6 months) ?

I tried googling, but was not able to find anything (maybe i'm not searching for the right keywords).

Thanks
--Andrew

Comment: You should be able to use the Jenkins API to query all the jobs, all the builds within that time period for each job, and which agent was used to run each build of each job.

Comment: You could iterate over the list of nodes and examine the [rss feeds](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#doRssAll-org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest-org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerResponse-).